# About android project that contains the Parse Initialization

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hello there I am trying to run my app which has code for login. As soon as I run the application it shows me a crash. It is saying that Parse to be initialized where I already did that and follow some other suggestion as well but no luck at all. Could you please help me out of it? Here I post few screenshots of that.

[image: This is my logcat description]

[image: This is my Login screen first few lines of code which is most probably the responsible one to crash the app]

Comment: please don't give the screenshot, paste the log_cat trace here. Nothing is visible in this one.

Answer (score 2):

This exception is triggered when Parse.com library initialization did not happen. Do you call `Parse.initialize()` in your `Application` class `onCreate()` method? If so could you provide source of this method?